# Change DNS server by editing /etc/resolv.conf file (using sed) and problem

Tags: linux, shell, sed, dns

I want to change the DNS server for my Linux machine. So, I'm going to edit /etc/resolv.conf file.

The command I'm using is **SED**. And doing as below for change DNS server to **192.168.1.5**:
`#cat /etc/resolv.conf | sed '/nameserver/ c\ nameserver 192.168.1.5' > /etc/resolv.conf`

The problem is:

When I execute the command the first time and it changes the resolv.conf to something like:

`domain somedomain

namserver 192.168.1.5`

but when I execute it once again to change DNS server to 192.168.1.4:
`#cat /etc/resolv.conf | sed '/nameserver/ c\ nameserver 192.168.1.4' > /etc/resolv.conf`

**The file resolv.conf becomes empty**

Questions:
1. Am I doing the right way to change DNS server?
2. Is there problem with the **sed** command in the above command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `>` redirection operates, the output file is truncated before any of the commands are run, which means the `cat` ought to see an empty file so the expected result is nothing.  I am a bit puzzled as to why your first invocation works.  You should use a temporary file (e.g. `mv resolv.conf resolv.conf~` and run `sed -e '...' resolv.conf~ > resolv.conf`, no need for `cat`).  Alternatively, if you have GNU sed you can use the in-place editing option (`sed -i`), again no need for `cat`.

Comment: Thanks @jw013, I tried a lot of times and the 1st time always worked. I got it a little clearer about `sed and cat` command. I will use the temporary file

Answer (score 2):

use this code (untested):

```
sed 's/nameserver.*/nameserver 192.168.1.5/' /etc/resolf.conf > /etc/resolf.conf.new
mv /etc/resolf.conf.new /etc/resolf.conf
```

Comment: Such a quick answer. Thanks a lot. I will test it and report

Comment: I tested your commands and unfortunatetly could not use mv command in /etc. Anyway thanks for the suggestion. I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine doing something like the following. Use sed to manipulate the cat stream to a different file, then validate this new file somehow e.g. count the number of lines and if the new file is valid replace the new file with /etc/resolv.conf.

Could be something like this:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf | sed "s/.*nameserver.*/nameserver 192.168.1.5/" > /etc/resolv.conf.sed;

if [ "$(wc -l /etc/resolv.conf.sed)" -eq "0" ]; then
    rm /etc/resolv.conf.sed;
fi;

if [ -e /etc/resolv.conf.sed ]; then
    mv /etc/resolv.conf.sed /etc/resolv.conf
fi;
```

Only the last line, well try counting the lines first, use head to print all lines but one to the output file and use tail to print the last line, perform the sed manipulation and *append* to the output file, like so:

```
I=$(wc -l /etc/resolv.conf | cut -d\/ -f1);
N=$[I-1];
head -n$N /etc/resolv.conf > /etc/resolv.conf.sed
tail -n1 /etc/resolv.conf | sed "s/.*nameserver.*/nameserver 192.168.1.5/" >> /etc/resolv.conf.sed;

if [ "$(wc -l /etc/resolv.conf.sed)" -eq "$I" ]; then
    rm /etc/resolv.conf.sed;
fi;

if [ -e /etc/resolv.conf.sed ]; then
    mv /etc/resolv.conf.sed /etc/resolv.conf
fi;
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the validation part. Will test if it works or not

Comment: could you tell me the way to only change the last line ( in case there are two lines of `nameserver` in resolv.conf) using sed command. There is any syntax to do it?

Comment: I tested but could not use the command: **mv** because /etc is `read-only file system`. So, I will write the file resolv.conf.sed to somewhere like /tmp and use **cat** to change /etc/resolv.conf ( can not remove this file but can change its content)

Comment: To change the last line only, it would be much easier to simply prepend the address range "`$`" to the `s` command of `sed`, like `sed -e '$ s/pattern/replacement'`, which tells `sed` to run the `s` command on the last line only.

Answer (score 0):

Sed has **in-file edition**; this is how I would do it (if I'm sure that there is just only one nameserver defined in that file; otherwise I'd do other things, but I guess that they are out of this question). In the example sed generates a resolv.conf_bak file for safety.

```
~# NAMESERVER=192.168.1.5;
~# sed -i_bak "s/\(nameserver\) .*/\1 $NAMESERVER/" /etc/resolv.conf
```

And this is a more elaborate command:

1. checks if there is a nameserver entry
2. if so edits it with sed
3. and if not creates a new one

This is the code:

```
~# grep -q  nameserver /etc/resolv.conf && sed -i_bak "s/\(nameserver\) .*/\1 $NAMESERVER/" /etc/resolv.conf || echo "nameserver $NAMESERVER" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Again provided that you work with just a **single** nameserver entry!